# How to recreate this equation in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, arrowwithtext

I am taking notes in LaTeX for sometime now. But I'm stuck with this one now. I want to create the equation below in LaTeX.
[image: A picture of the equation I want to recreate]

I tried using `\underbrace` `\Centerstack` command but I don't know how to create arrows like above. And the text color isn't much important. This is all I was able to achieve.

[image: This is all I could achieve]

Edit: Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools} 

\begin{document} 

\Centerstack{FCFF} = \text{NOPLAT} + \underbrace{\Centerstack{Non-cash Operating Expenses} - \Centerstack{Investment in Invested   Capital}}_{\text{Net Investment}}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, text alignment isn't much that good too.

I think you can understand what I want to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please show us what you try so far, i.e. by which code you produce the second image!

Comment: `tikzmark` library is your friend on this one. Drop your MWE here and we'll help you out.

Comment: Thank you. I'll update my question with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not pretty code, but the formula isn't pretty, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\textup{FCFF}+
\textup{NOPLAT}+
{\underbrace{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} Non-cash \\ Operating Expenses \end{tabular}%
  \;-\;
  \overset{\substack{\textup{Gross Investment\smash[t]{\strut}}\\\big\downarrow}}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} Investments in \\ Invested Capitals \end{tabular}%
  }
}_{\textup{Not Investment}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added `\smash[t]{\strut}` to add some vertical space above the down arrow; also some space around the minus sign to make it more visible.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\text{FCFF}+\text{NOPLAT}
=\underbrace{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Non-cash\\
operating expenses\end{tabular}
-\overset{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Gross investment}\\
\downarrow
\end{array}}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Investment in\\
invested capital\end{tabular}}}_{\text{Net Investment}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have made some small changes to your 2nd screenshot that make your formula slightly clearer and I have added the specific font for your second image.
Here there is my approach.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{helvet} 
\usepackage{courier}

\begin{document}
\[\textnormal{FCFF}=\textnormal{NOPLAT}+\underbrace{\begin{matrix} \textnormal{Non-cash} 
\\ \,\text{Operating} \\ \textnormal{Expenses} \end{matrix}
\quad -\quad  \overset{\overset{\textnormal{Gross Investment}}{\downarrow}}{\begin{matrix} \textnormal{Investments} \\ \textnormal{in} \\ \textnormal{Invested Capitals}
\end{matrix}}}_{\textnormal{Not Investment}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]